# Average over last 7 days formula in google sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

My 1-year-old son was just diagnosed with Type 1 Diabetes, and I am trying to create a spreadsheet to track his sugar levels etc. I have the dates in column A, and his blood sugar levels in column C. I have been trying for the last couple days to figure out how to get his average blood sugar levels for the last 7 days, and just keep getting errors. I have searched google extensively, and have found some similar examples, but can never seem to get them to work.

This is what I have at the moment, but I get a Divide by zero error.

```
=averageif(A7:A, ">=" & (TODAY()-6),C7:C)
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Comment: `A7:A` is not a valid range. You need a closing row number. Same as `C7:C`.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I think that is valid syntax in Google Sheets (maybe the Excel tag should be removed). Edit: I removed it.

Comment: I tried the original formula and it seemed to be OK. Maybe something wrong with the date formats?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C2:C, A2:A, "<="&TODAY(), A2:A, ">="&TODAY()-6)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Thank you! I just shared my sheet with you.

Comment: use: `=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(C7:C, A7:A, "<="&TODAY(), A7:A, ">="&TODAY()-6), "no measurments in last 7 days")`

Comment: DIV error was caused because there are no measurements in last 7 days

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=AVERAGE(IFNA(QUERY(A2:C, 
 "select C 
  where A <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),   "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and A >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-6, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?